# How to dynamically change page number in FormRequest on POST request when crawling multiple page using Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, macos, scrapy

The website that I wanna crawl is using POST method to get data, instead of navigating to paginating url. Getting the first page looks great now, using this method:

```
    def start_requests(self):
        formdata = {
            ...
            'PageIndex': '0',
            ...
        }
        return [
            FormRequest('my-url', formdata=formdata, callback=self.parse)
        ]
```

I checked the next page and tried to `yield` the next page as following code:

```
    current_page = 0
    ....

    def parse(self, response):
        next_page = Selector(response).css('a.viewmore').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            self.current_page = self.current_page + 1
            formdata = {
                ...
                'PageIndex': self.current_page,
                ...
            }
            yield FormRequest('my-url', formdata=formdata, callback=self.parse)
```

This is where it is broken. I got the error log here, and I can only assume that the way I assign `self.current_page` causes the broken result.

[image]

I am using `macOS`, `python3` (version `3.8.1`), `scrapy` `1.8.0`.Could anyone guide me on this one and help me to assign dynamic page number on `POST` request like this? Thanks in advance!

---

Update: I have figured out that the line `self.current_page` should be cast as following: `'PageIndex': str(self.current_page)`. This problem is solved!

Comment: Have you tried to cast it as `str` ?

Comment: Oh shoot! I have figured out that earlier. Since this is the first time I try `python`, I had thought that it's because of something else inside python core, instead of just variable type. It worked btw and thank you for your concern.